# Create a formatted table in ipython-notebook with variables as cell entries?

Tags: linux, html-table, format, jupyter-notebook

I started using python and ipython notebook a few days ago and am excited about the possibilities. I have what I hope is a very basic question. I am trying to present the results of my calculations in a convenient and if possible, somewhat attractive table. Something like:

```
s = '''<table>
<tr>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Units</th>
<th>Heading 1</th>
<th>Heading 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>uA</td>
<td>ft/s</td>
<td>uAi</td>
<td>uAf</td>
</tr>
</table>'''
h = HTML(s); h
```

The final table would have about 6 or so rows, but you can get the idea of what I am trying to create.

What I would like though is to have the quantities, uAi & uAf to show up as their numerical results, preferably formatted as floating point numbers with 2 decimal places. Is there an easy way to do this without resorting to something like Pandas?

The reason I want to avoid Pandas is that I think it may cause my computer problems. I run a 64-bit version of Kubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin). I attempted to install the python-pandas package from the repositories and it wanted to UNinstall the following packages:

```
linux-headers-3.2.0-23{u},
linux-headers-3.2.0.23-generic{u}, 
nvidia-settings{u}, 
nvidia-settings-experimental-304{u}
```

Comment: Possibly those are packages the system doesn't need anymore and may not have anything to do with the new installation of your package.

Comment: You are a very smart freak! I was very surprised to see those packages flagged by the install for python-pandas, but so far it doesn't seem to have borked my system having removed them. +1 for you?